# React JS dynamic loading components with Json Array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

In My Next JS app, I need to load diffrent components, using react dynamic components, I here I have st to load product in every button click, According to the blow code buttons `Product`,`My List`,`Tasks`

**This is my page**

```
"use client";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
import {
  Bars4Icon,
  ClockIcon,
  HomeIcon,
} from "@heroicons/react/24/outline";

function page() {
  const [sidebarOpen, setSidebarOpen] = useState(false);
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const navigation = [
    { id: 1, name: "Product", href: "#", icon: HomeIcon, current: true },
    { id: 2, name: "My List", href: "#", icon: Bars4Icon, current: false },
    { id: 3, name: "Tasks", href: "#", icon: ClockIcon, current: false },
  ];


  function classNames(...classes) {
    return classes.filter(Boolean).join(" ");
  }

  const Product = dynamic(() => import("../../pages/product"), {
    ssr: false,
    loading: () => <p> I am fetching</p>,
  });
  return (
    <>
      <div className="min-h-full">

        {/* Static sidebar for desktop */}
        <div className="hidden lg:fixed lg:inset-y-0 lg:flex lg:w-64 lg:flex-col lg:border-r lg:border-gray-200 lg:bg-gray-100 lg:pt-5 lg:pb-4">
          {/* Sidebar component, swap this element with another sidebar if you like */}
          <div className="mt-5 flex h-0 flex-1 flex-col overflow-y-auto pt-1">
            {/* Navigation */}
            <nav className="mt-6 px-3">
              <div className="space-y-1">
                {navigation.map((item) => (
                  <a
                    key={item.name}
                    id={item.id}
                    href={item.href}
                    className={classNames(
                      item.current
                        ? "bg-gray-200 text-gray-900"
                        : "text-gray-700 hover:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-50",
                      "group flex items-center px-2 py-2 text-sm font-medium rounded-md"
                    )}
                    aria-current={item.current ? "page" : undefined}
                    onClick={() => setShow(true)}
                  >
                    <item.icon
                      className={classNames(
                        item.current
                          ? "text-gray-500"
                          : "text-gray-400 group-hover:text-gray-500",
                        "mr-3 flex-shrink-0 h-6 w-6"
                      )}
                      aria-hidden="true"
                    />
                    {item.name}
                  </a>
                ))}
              </div>
            </nav>
          </div>
        </div>
        {/* Main column */}
        <div className="flex flex-col lg:pl-64">
          {/* Search header */}
          <div>{show && <Product />}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default page;
```

**This is my Component**   (Other components [Product,My List,Tasks] also same like this)

````
import { useState } from "react";

function product() {
  const [sidebarOpen, setSidebarOpen] = useState(false);
  return (
    <>
      {/*
        This example requires updating your template:
        ```
        <html class="h-full bg-white">
        <body class="h-full">
        ```
      */}
      <div className="min-h-full">
        {/* Main column */}
          {/* Search header */}
          <main className="flex-1">
            {/* Page title & actions */}
            <div className="border-b border-gray-200 px-4 py-4 sm:flex sm:items-center sm:justify-between sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
              <div className="min-w-0 flex-1">
                <h1 className="text-lg font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900 sm:truncate">
                  Products
                </h1>
              </div>
              <div className="mt-4 flex sm:mt-0 sm:ml-4">
                <button
                  type="button"
                  className="sm:order-0 order-1 ml-3 inline-flex items-center rounded-md border border-gray-300 bg-white px-4 py-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 shadow-sm hover:bg-gray-50 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-purple-500 focus:ring-offset-2 sm:ml-0"
                >
                  Share
                </button>
                <button
                  type="button"
                  className="order-0 inline-flex items-center rounded-md border border-transparent bg-purple-600 px-4 py-2 text-sm font-medium text-white shadow-sm hover:bg-purple-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-purple-500 focus:ring-offset-2 sm:order-1 sm:ml-3"
                >
                  Create
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </main>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default product;
````

This is how look like the page, What I need to do is When click the product I need load product component.
[image]